# What do I have to change in the code for an OpenGL triangle to make an OpenGL line? (LWJGL 2.9) (VAOs and VBOs)

Tags: java, lwjgl, vbo, vao

I have only found tutorials etc for legacy ways of drawing (i.e. GL_BEGIN() being used). I want to use things like VAOs and VBOs. I am capable with OpenGL Triangles and using Index buffers but that doesn't apply to Lines.

I am looking for responses highlighting the ways it is different for GL_LINES compared to GL_TRIANGLES. This way, I'm not being told exactly what to do but I'm not just being directed to another resource.

Here is the basic code I use for Triangles (without index buffers, shaders and textures)

```
    int vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays ( );
    GL30.glBindVertexArray ( vao );

    //@formatter:off
    float[] verts = {
        -0.5f , -0.5f ,
         0.5f , -0.5f ,
         0.0f ,  0.5f
    };
    //@formatter:on

    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer ( verts.length );
    buffer.put ( verts );
    buffer.flip ( );

    int vbo = GL15.glGenBuffers ( );

    GL15.glBindBuffer ( GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , vbo );

    GL15.glBufferData ( GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , buffer , GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer ( 0 , 3 , GL11.GL_FLOAT , false , 0 , 0 );
    GL11.glDrawArrays ( GL11.GL_TRIANGLES , 0 , 3 );

    GL30.glBindVertexArray ( 0 );
```

What are the differences between this code and the code for a Line?

Comment: Your introduction does not make clear why you are not changing `GL11.GL_TRIANGLES` into `GL11.GL_LINES` - or, if you did, what the problem was with that.

Comment: @RadLexus I have realized why the lines weren't rendering. I didn't have a shader set up. I realized it after trying the Rubber Ducky Method! I only tried it as a joke and because I was so stressed but it actually worked. I realized the problem with rendering. Should I just delete this question?